# CSS styling not applied to html

Tags: html, css

I initially was loading a page

```
<a href="/app/tos/blabla/en" target="_blank">somePage</a>
```

And the index.html would render with styling

```
<head>
    ..
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/themes/basic_themes/blabla/base_theme/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/themes/defaults/generated.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/themes/basic_themes/blabla/generated.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/themes/brands/blabla/generated.css">
    <script src="/js/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The above code works fine in production. However someone made some changes and deleted the app folder and refactored the code to this:

```
<a href="/tos/blabla/en" target="_blank">somePage</a>
```

And the index.html to

```
<head>
    ..
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/basic_themes/blabla/base_theme/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/defaults/generated.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/basic_themes/blabla/generated.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/brands/blabla/generated.css">
    <script src="/js/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Now index.html cannot find the css styling. I tried different relative and absolute paths but nothing seems to work.

Any help?

**EDIT**: My folder structure is:

[image: My folder structure]

When I load my page localy http://localhost:56071/blabla/en/ and then click to navigate to "somePage" I end up on http://localhost:56071/tos/blabla/en/ a page with text and no styling. However, if I try to navigate to http://localhost:56071/themes/basic_themes/blabla/base_theme/bootstrap.min.css it returns a 404. BUT I can access my .css file through this link http://localhost:56071/blabla/en/themes/basic_themes/blabla/base_theme/bootstrap.min.css Can someone explain whats happening here?

Comment: Can you please include your file structure?

Comment: I have added my folder structure

Comment: I don't see any reason why this should work. Please attach all examples of relative/absolute paths You've tried. Wasn't the index.html moved to some different folder? Aren't there any limitations based on `.htaccess`? Also try to open in some inteligent browser (e.g. `Chrome`), inspect the row with CSS link and R-click -> open in new tab. What is result?

Comment: What server engine are You using? It simply means that it changes the path of the files to be accessible just through the prefix `http://localhost:56071/blabla/en/`. Based on the engine and framework You can check how the paths are created and possible change it to provide the correct one.